# Matplotlib plot_surface transparency artefact

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a surface in 3D from a set of data which specifies the z-values. I get some weird transparency artefact though, where I can see through the surface, even though I set alpha=1.0.

The artefact is present both when plotting and when saved to file (both as png and pdf):
[image]

I have tried changing the line width, and changing the number of strides from 1 to 10 (in the latter case, the surface is not visible though due to too rough resolution).

**Q: How can I get rid of this transparency?**

Here is my code:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

y_label = r'x'
x_label = r'y'
z_label = r'z'

x_scale = 2.0*np.pi
y_scale = 2.0*np.pi

y_numPoints = 250
x_numPoints = 250

def quasiCrystal(x, y):
    z = 0
    for i in range(0,5):
        z += np.sin(x * np.cos(float(i)*np.pi/5.0) +
                    y * np.sin(float(i)*np.pi/5.0))
    return z

x = np.linspace(-x_scale, x_scale, x_numPoints)
y = np.linspace(-y_scale, y_scale, y_numPoints)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

Z = quasiCrystal(X, Y)


f = plt.figure()
ax = f.gca(projection='3d')

surf = ax.plot_surface( X, Y, Z,
                        rstride=5, cstride=5,
                        cmap='seismic',
                        alpha=1,
                        linewidth=0,
                        antialiased=True,
                        vmin=np.min(Z),
                        vmax=np.max(Z)
                      )

ax.set_zlim3d(np.min(Z), np.max(Z))

f.colorbar(surf, label=z_label)

ax.set_xlabel(x_label)
ax.set_ylabel(y_label)
ax.set_zlabel(z_label)

plt.show()
```

Here is another picture of my actual data where it is easier to see the artefact:
[image]

Comment: Provide a sample of your data so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Updated with sample data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Matplotlib is not a "real" 3D engine. This is a very well known problem and once in a while a similar question to yours appears appears (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37488379/matplotlib-3dplot-extra-lines-when-dimensions-not-equal/37489040#37489040) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37380912/matplotlib-3d-plot-plot-surface-black/37501084#37501084)). The problem is that the same artefact can originate problems that seem to be different. I believe such is the case for you.

Before going on with my recommendations let me just [quote this information from the matplotlib website](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/faq.html):

> **My 3D plot doesn’t look right at certain viewing angles**
>
> This is probably the most commonly reported issue with mplot3d. The problem is
> that – from some viewing angles – a 3D object would appear in front of
> another object, even though it is physically behind it. This can
> result in plots that do not look “physically correct.”
>
> Unfortunately, while some work is being done to reduce the occurance
> of this artifact, it is currently an intractable problem, and **can not**
> **be fully solved until matplotlib supports 3D graphics rendering at its**
> **core**.
>
> The problem occurs due to the reduction of 3D data down to 2D +
> z-order scalar. A single value represents the 3rd dimension for all
> parts of 3D objects in a collection. Therefore, when the bounding
> boxes of two collections intersect, it becomes possible for this
> artifact to occur. Furthermore, the intersection of two 3D objects
> (such as polygons or patches) can not be rendered properly in
> matplotlib’s 2D rendering engine.
>
> **This problem will likely not be solved until OpenGL support is added**
> to all of the backends (patches are greatly welcomed). Until then, if
> you need complex 3D scenes, we recommend using [MayaVi](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/).

[It seems that Mayavi has finally moved on to Python 3](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/changes.html?highlight=python3), so its certainly a possibility. If you want to stick with matplotlib for this kind of plot my advice is that you work with rstride and cstride values to see which ones produce a plot satisfactory to you.

```
surf = ax.plot_surface( X, Y, Z,
                        rstride=5, cstride=5,
                        cmap='jet',
                        alpha=1,
                        linewidth=0,
                        antialiased=True,
                        vmin=0,
                        rstride=10,
                        cstride=10,
                        vmax=z_scale
                      )
```

Other possibility is to try to see if other kinds of 3D plots do better. Check [plot_trisurf](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#tri-surface-plots), [contour](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#contour-plots) or [contourf](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#filled-contour-plots). I know its not ideal but in the past I also managed to [circumvent other type of artefacts using 3D polygons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36737053/mplot3d-fill-between-extends-over-axis-limits/36738573#36738573).

Sorry for not having a more satisfactory answer. Perhaps other SO users have better solutions for this. Best of luck.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824893/how-to-draw-intersecting-planes/14825951#14825951

Answer (score 8):

I ran into some similar issues and found that they were antialiasing artifacts and could be fixed by setting `antialiased=False` in `plot_surface`.