# Why a sphere created with ax.pltsurface is not being able to keep the desired alpha=1 in the faces of the surface?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

> I am showing a color map as the facecolors of a sphere using **ax.plt_surface**. Basically is the example that is available at the pyplot webpages, with some extra code to add the color map. The application generates a complex function f(z)=z^3+1 for z=a+bi where a=[-4,4] and b=[-3,3]. Then the domain color map of the function is done, it is a [200]x[200]x3 numpy array (the typical one). Finally the sphere is created and I want to use the color map as the filling color of the faces of the surface of the sphere, so basically I want to map the color map as the "texture" of the sphere.

```
def sphere_mapping():
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import skimage, skimage.io
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
    from math import sqrt, atan2, pi

    def hslToRgb(h, s, l):
        # Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353211/hsl-to-rgb-color-conversion
        # Converts an HSL color value to RGB. Conversion formula
        # adapted from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_color_space.
        # Assumes h, s, and l are contained in the set [0, 1] and
        # returns r, g, and b in the set [0, 1].
        def hue2rgb(p, q, t):
            if t < 0:
                t += 1
            if t > 1:
                t -= 1
            if t < 1/6:
                return p + (q - p) * 6 * t
            if t < 1/2:
                return q
            if t < 2/3:
                return p + (q - p) * (2/3 - t) * 6
            return p

        r,g,b = 0,0,0

        if s == 0:
            r,g,b = l,l,l
        else:
            q=0
            if l < 0.5:
                q=l * (1 + s)
            else:
                q=l + s - l * s

            p = 2 * l - q;
            r = hue2rgb(p, q, h + 1/3)
            g = hue2rgb(p, q, h)
            b = hue2rgb(p, q, h - 1/3)

        return r,g,b

    # Displays an image
    def display(img, colorbar=False, filename=""):
        plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
        if len(img.shape) == 2:
            i = skimage.io.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
        else:
            i = skimage.io.imshow(img)
        if colorbar:
            plt.colorbar(i, shrink=0.5, label='depth')
        plt.tight_layout()
        if filename=="":
            plt.show()
        else:
            plt.savefig(filename)

    plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 150    

    # complex function f(z) calculations start here
    testlimitx = 100
    testlimity = 100
    testbase = 100

    anim=0
    lx=[]
    ly=[]
    lc=[]

    lh=[]
    ll=[]
    lr=[]
    ls=[]

    print("Calculating...")
    maxx=0
    maxy=0

    for posx in range(-testlimitx,testlimitx):
        for posy in range(-testlimity,testlimity):

            x=(posx/testbase)*1
            y=(posy/testbase)*1

            # function complex example
            myc=x+(y*(1j))
            myc=(myc**3)+1

            resx=myc.real
            resy=myc.imag

            if abs(resx)>maxx:
                maxx=abs(resx)
            if abs(resy)>maxy:
                maxy=abs(resy)

            current_angle = 0
            current_r = sqrt((resx**2)+(resy**2))
            if resx!=0:
                current_angle = atan2(resy,resx)
            else:
                if y>0:
                    current_angle = pi/2
                else:
                    current_angle = (pi/2)*3

            if current_angle < 0:
                current_angle = current_angle + (2*pi)

            current_angle = (1/(2*pi))*current_angle

            h = current_angle
            l = 0.5
            s = 0.7

            lx.append(x)
            ly.append(y)

            lh.append(h)    
            ll.append(l)    
            ls.append(s)
            lr.append(current_r)    

    for i in range(0,len(lx)):
        r,g,b = hslToRgb(lh[i], ls[i], ll[i])

        # lc contains 200x200x3 R,G,B color values
        lc.append(r)
        lc.append(g)
        lc.append(b)

    print("Creating colormap ...")
    colormap = np.zeros((200, 200, 3), dtype=np.float)
    pos=0
    for i in range (0,200):
        for j in range (1,201):
            colormap[200-j][i][0]=lc[pos]
            pos=pos+1
            colormap[200-j][i][1]=lc[pos]
            pos=pos+1
            colormap[200-j][i][2]=lc[pos]
            pos=pos+1
            print("Current index="+str(i)+","+str(j)+"\r", end='')

    # finally this is the colormap that has been generated
    display(colormap)

    # sphere test: will map the colormap into the surface of the sphere
    n=200
    m=200
    u = np.linspace(0,2*pi,n)
    v = np.linspace(0,pi,m)

    x = np.outer(np.cos(u),np.sin(v))
    y = np.outer(np.sin(u),np.sin(v))
    z = np.outer(np.ones(n),np.cos(v))

    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.patch.set_alpha(1)
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
    ax.view_init(elev=0., azim=-180)    

    col1 = np.empty([n,m,3], dtype=float)
    for i in range(0,len(col1)):
        for j in range(0,len(col1[i])):
            col1[i][j][1]=colormap[j][i][0]
            col1[i][j][1]=colormap[j][i][1]
            col1[i][j][2]=colormap[j][i][2]

    ax.plot_surface(x,y,z,color='b',rstride=1, cstride=1, alpha=1.0, linewidth=0, facecolors=col1)
    plt.show()
    plt.savefig("sphere_test.png", dpi=600)

sphere_mapping()
```

The color map image of the above example is the following one:

[image]

But when I view the image as the surface of the sphere after mapping it to the numpy array "col1" (the mapping is just because the information of the colors of the points are located in different places of the array but the dimensions of both arrays are the same ones), the colors are not matching, and I guess that it is due to some undesired transparency, so I cannot see exclusively the color of the current side I am facing (I can see due to the transparency the hidden side as well and the colors are mixing). I have added alpha=1.0 but it seems that is not making the desired effect. I was expecting exactly the same colors, no transparency, so no mixed colors expected.

[image]

I am not sure if this is related with the [topic in this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39144482/matplotlib-plot-surface-transparency-artefact).

Currently I am using the following parameters for the **ax.plotsurface** call:

ax.plot_surface(x,y,z,color='b',rstride=1, cstride=1, alpha=1.0, linewidth=0, facecolors=col1)

> Is it possible to fix this problem? Thank you!

Comment: What is `colormap`? See [mcve].

Comment: Quoting from the close reasons: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: I think you will understand that it is really hard to see what's going on without a working example code. Once you have that in the question, you may notify me again and I will have a look at it.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thank you for your time, it is really appreciated! I have added the full code, as simple as possible to show the issue. Basically it is a math test, the image is a complex domain color map of the complex function f(z)=z^3+1 and I just want to map that "bitmap" or "color map" into the faces of the sphere, but I think the sphere is not totally opaque and that is the reason why I see darker colors: it is mixing the colors of the hidden part of the sphere with the "front side" (where the camera is located) of the sphere.

Comment: This code takes 3 minutes to complete. Sorry, that is too much for testing.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest sorry, I have updated with same example for [200]x[200]x[3], now it takes 14secs. I hope will be fine now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that the only problem is the mapping of colors to `col1`. Instead of

```
col1[i][j][1]=colormap[j][i][0]
col1[i][j][1]=colormap[j][i][1]
col1[i][j][2]=colormap[j][i][2]
```

you may want

```
col1[i][j][0]=colormap[j][i][0]
col1[i][j][1]=colormap[j][i][1]
col1[i][j][2]=colormap[j][i][2]
```

Comment: I am deeply appreciated, it was! sadly I was too stubborn (or blind) thinking that the issue was in the call to the function. Lessons learned!